# Trouble with Mass-Assignment Error for Admin User

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I was trying to follow the railscasts tutorial that explains how to handle mass-assignment errors and attr_accessible for admins, but since that was a little outdated, I'm trying to follow what's in the rails API dock for 3.2.6 [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-mass_assignment_sanitizer-3D).

All I want to do is allow the admin user the ability to access the "winning" attribute for the Proposal Model on the Update action.

Here's my Proposal Model showing the current attr_accessible.

```
class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :email, :email_confirmation, :link, :name, :references, :short_description

belongs_to :idea
```

Here's my code for the Proposal Controller's Update action.

```
class ProposalsController < ApplicationController

include ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity
attr_accessible :email, :email_confirmation, :link, :name, :references, :short_description
attr_accessible :email, :email_confirmation, :link, :name, :references, :short_description, :winning, :as => :admin

def update
    @idea = Idea.find(params[:idea_id])
    @proposal = @idea.proposals.find(params[:id])

    if @proposal.update_attributes(proposal_params)
        redirect_to idea_proposals_url(@idea)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

protected

    def proposal_params
        role = current_user.admin ? :admin : :default
        sanitize_for_mass_assignment(params[:proposal], role)
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this Railscast. I had a similar issue with an Admin field Boolean and didn't want any user to circumvent the security by sending a curl post. If the user is an admin then it gave them the ability to access the field, otherwise Mass Assignment would protect the field from being modified.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/237-dynamic-attr-accessible?view=asciicast

Comment: I've tried to implement it but im getting this error: undefined method `admin?'

Comment: Do you have a boolean field in your table called `admin`?